# Yii2 show flash message in a pop up or spinner

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, popup, flash-message

Is there any way to show a flash message in a pop-up or a spinner. Right now I am displaying a flash message with custom `jQuery` to hide it.

**In Controller**

```
\Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'Verification Failed..... Try GPRS Communication again!!');
```

**In View**

```
<div id="statusMsg" >
                     <?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('error');?>
         </div>

$(document).ready(function(){
              setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#statusMsg').fadeOut('fast');
               }, 5000); // <-- time in milliseconds
      });
```

I want to show this flash message in a pop-up or a spinner.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

i extends alert widget by Kartik. And use it.

```
  class AlertModal extends \yii\bootstrap\Widget
    {

...........
 public $alertTypes = [
        'modal-error' => 'alert-error',
        'modal-danger' => 'alert-danger',
        'modal-success' => 'alert-success',
        'modal-info' => 'alert-info',
        'modal-warning' => 'alert-warning'
    ];
    .........
        public function init()
        {
    ......

Modal::begin([
   'id' => 'modal-' . $this->options['id'],
   'header' => '<h2>warning</h2>',
   'toggleButton' => false,
   'clientOptions' => ['show' => true]
]);
/** original part  */
  echo \yii\bootstrap\Alert::widget([
      'body' => $message,
     'closeButton' => false,
      'options' => $this->options,
      ]);
/** \original part */
  Modal::end();

.....
}
...
}
```

in layout:

```
 <?= \app\components\widgets\AlertModal::widget() ?>
 <?= Alert::widget() ?>
```

in controller:

```
Yii::$app->session->setFlash('modal-danger', 'you message');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use Kartik Growl extension: http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/growl

View layout/main

```
use kartik\growl\Growl;
<body>
.....
   <?php foreach (Yii::$app->session->getAllFlashes() as $message):;  ?>
        <?php

        echo Growl::widget([
            'type' => (!empty($message['type'])) ? $message['type'] : 'danger',
            'title' => (!empty($message['title'])) ? Html::encode($message['title']) : 'Title Not Set!',
            'icon' => (!empty($message['icon'])) ? $message['icon'] : 'fa fa-info',
            'body' => (!empty($message['message'])) ? Html::encode($message['message']) : 'Message Not Set!',
            'showSeparator' => true,
            'delay' => 1, //This delay is how long before the message shows
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'delay' => (!empty($message['duration'])) ? $message['duration'] : 3000, //This delay is how long the message shows for
                'placement' => [
                    'from' => (!empty($message['positonY'])) ? $message['positonY'] : 'top',
                    'align' => (!empty($message['positonX'])) ? $message['positonX'] : 'right',
                ]
            ],
            'useAnimation'=>true
        ]);
        ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</body>
```

Controller.php

```
public function actionSome(){
  .......your code here
  Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', [
                             'type' => 'success',
                             'duration' => 5000,
                             'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                             'message' => ' your Message',
                             'title' => 'Title of pop up',
                             'positonY' => 'top',
                             'positonX' => 'right'
                         ]);
    return $this->render('yourview');
}
```